# Can I Authorize database access based on membership in a Facebook group

Tags: database, facebook

I'm part of a Facebook group for people who graduated from my high school. One of the members of the group keeps a running comment in which he posts the names and details of the former students who have died. You can look through the names, but it's not very easy to determine if a particular classmate is in the list. I thought of creating a database to hold that information but I wanted to limit access to people in the FB group. I wonder if it's possible to give access to group members through FB rather than manually adding each of them to the database access list.

Comment: did you check out the docs already, to try some stuff? the api reference would tell you exactly what´s possible, including example code.

Comment: @luschn I haven't. The point of asking the question is to avoid having to search all the documentation but instead rely on the expertise of others. If someone answered the question "yes" then I would go dig out the details. If the answer were "no", I'd save a lot of wasted effort searching for something that isn't there.

Comment: no, that´s not what stackoverflow is about, i´m afraid. this is a platform for developers, you are required to do some research and testing before asking. if you get stuck, we are very happy to help. but there is no shortcut for learning the basics ;)

Comment: in other words: always hit the docs first.

Comment: @luschn You have a right to your opinion about how to use stackoverflow and I have a right to mine. When you don't know the answer to a question, it's best just to remain silent.

Comment: i did not tell you my opinion, those are the rules of stackoverflow. if you don´t even want to hit the docs before asking, it´s best to hire a developer. sorry if that sounds harsh, but that´s just not how stackoverflow works. right now your question is just too broad, show us what you have tried so far and where exactly you got stuck.

Comment: @luschn I don't need to hire a developer because I've been one since the 80s. I've seen a lot of good content on stackoverflow from developers who don't have the "just google it" mentality, who aren't more interested in "closing" questions than answering them, who don't try to tell people that they don't want to do what they asked about and aren't overly concerned with the silly gamification. I'll continue to ask questions I want to ask and I'll continue to help people when I can and STFU when I can't help.